# ¿Comó comparó cada fila que resulta de mi consulta con una variable?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$Folio=$_POST['folio'];
echo "Folio:".$Folio;
$query=$mysqli->query("SELECT folio FROM reservaciones WHERE status=1");
while($f=$query->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo "Folio: ".$f['folio'];
if ($f['folio']==$Folio) {

    header("location: carro.php");
}else{
echo "Folio erroneo";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema que tenes?

Comment: No se entiende cual es tu problema o que es lo que quieres hacer